# Regarding SQL connection string

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

How should I create my SQL connection string in c# (esp. username and password), if I'm using windows authentication mode to connect to my SQL server. I tried using the system login credentials, but it's not working. When i try to open the connection, I'm getting "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" exception.

Please help..

Comment: Where is your connection string located? Is it a `string` in your program (not recommended), or in your `app.config`?

Comment: I'm using string in the program (whatever it is..), the exception says login failed for <username>. But if I goto server and check the database properties, my username is there in the "owner" field.

Comment: If you don't have it, add `Trusted_Connection=True;` to the end of your connection string and see if that works.

Comment: After adding Trusted_Connection=True; excetion is not raised, but my values are not going to the table. anyways thanks..

Comment: Handy resource: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

Which "data provider" are you using?

If it's `System.Data.SqlClient` then below connection string should work fine.

```
"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;
    Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Server=MSSQL1"
```

Here is the link to MSDN article for more details.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500(v=vs.110).aspx

For more accurate answer, please provide exception details.

By the way, if want to use "Windows authentication mode" then you needn't to provide user name and password. "Windows authentication mode" means you are using current users credentials. IMHO